# PHP ftp_rmdir won't delete folder names containing spaces

Tags: php, ftp

A similar post about ftp_rmdir does not answer this question here. My script deletes FTP folders. This has always worked, until I hit folder names containing spaces:

Code:

`$result = ftp_rmdir ($conn_id, "encoding/bitte loeschen/birtegernhardt/Desktop");`

Result:

`PHP Warning:  ftp_rmdir(): encoding/bitte loeschen/birtegernhardt/Desktop: Directory not empty`

Note: the folder IS empty!

Enclosing the folder string in quotes has not helped. Should the space be replaced with a different character? I tried escaping it with \, then it says that the folder does not exist. Thanks for helping!

Comment: What OS is PHP running on?

Comment: Also, if you changed the name of that particular folder to remove the space, would your script delete as expected?

Comment: Debian 7.6. And you are right, after renaming the folder to .../bitte_loeschen/..., it still gives the same error when attempting to delete. But it is empty:

root@xxx:/ftp/encoding/bitte_loeschen/bitte_loeschen/birtegernhardt/Desktop# ls -l

total 0

Comment: I created a "test" folder in "encoding/bitte_loeschen/bitte_loeschen/birtegernhardt/", which deletes fine, but ".../Desktop" won't delete. Permissions are the same:

drwxr-xr-x 2 user ftpuser 4096 Aug 26 01:01 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 user ftpuser 4096 Aug 26 11:17 test

Comment: There's probably a 'dot file' or otherwise hidden in there somewhere. try `# ls -al` to show all files.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a file in there. It's probably a 'dot file' or otherwise hidden, but there is something in there somewhere. Try:

> `ls -al`

...to show all files.